# Algorithm task based on a variation of Fibonacci sequence

Tags: algorithm

> Being given parameters C and M, help decrypt a list of encrypted
>   integers. The former parameter is used for generating {a_n} and {s_n}
>   sequences, defined as follows:
>
> - a_1 = a_2 = 1
> - forall n>=1: a_(n+2) = C * a_(n+1) + a_n
> - forall n: s_n = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_n
>
> The ciphertext consists of T natural numbers. Each of them encrypts
>   one result number. In order to restore the original x value, it is
>   necessary to determine the result of the following operation: s_x mod
>   M
>
> Input: two natural numbers C and M, T denoting number of tests and T
>   lines consisting of only one x number.
>
> 1 <= C, M <= 10^18 
>   1 <= T <= 1000 
>   1 <= x <= 10^18
>
> Example input:
>
> 1 10 
>   5 
>   2 
>   3 
>   4 
>   10 
>   1
>
> Example output:
>
> 2  
>  4 
>   7 
>   3  
>  1

It's a problem that showed up at the Deadline24 algorithmic competition which took placce this morning and for the love of all that's holy, I couldn't think of any way of pruning the calculations so that you don't have to do 10^18 operations in the worst case scenario.

Any brute force approach is immediately cut out because of that, so is a naive recursion approach. We may note that the sequence is a variation on the Fibonacci sequnece but it doesn't help much as the sequences with C != 1 are divergent from the regular Fibonacci sequence and thus we can't apply any of the approximations like Binet's Fibonacci number formula to calculate F_(n+2) - 1 which would normally be the sum of the first n Fibonacci numbers.

I thought of expressing the terms with C only and applying some fast modpow but it falls short both because it's slow (we still have to calculate the coefficient at each term which is a loop for every power in the final sum) and hard to compute (it *looks* like there is a pattern but it soon becomes tedious and hard to prove how it will progress).

What's a good way of solving this for max inputs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but here's a general guideline for a possible solution: 1. Find a recurrence relation for s_n. 2. Express the relation using a matrix form as done [for fibonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form). 3. Use exponentiation by squaring of the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use matrix exponentiation to get a logarithmic solution:

```
f(n) = C*f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)

a b       f(n)                    
     *            = [f(n + 1)   f(n)]
c d     f(n - 1)
```

This results in:

```
a = C
b = 1
c = 1
d = 0
```

So you can use this matrix to get the `n`-th term of your function. As for the sum, notice that:

```
f(n)     = Cf(n - 1) + f(n - 2)
f(n - 1) = Cf(n - 2) + f(n - 3)
...
f(3)     = Cf(2)     + f(1)
=============================== +
s(n) - 2 = C(s(n - 1) - 1) + s(n - 2)
s(n) = Cs(n - 1) + s(n - 2) - (C - 2)
```

This isn't as nice as what you can do for the Fibonacci numbers (expressing the sum in terms of a single Fibonacci number), but it can be solved by [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) using a similar (3 x 3) matrix to the one of the initial recurrence, which you can find using the same method, and with different starting conditions:

```
s(1) = 1
s(2) = 2
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. But is using matrices the only way of solving this? It involves college-level maths which you aren't really able to derive off the top of your head if you don't know it already and I think algorithmic contests try to stay away from such tasks more often than not. Or maybe it's just that in this particular example, it wasn't the case?

Comment: @Straightfw - for problems such as this, there's no better way, you have to use matrices. It's not college-level math though, I learnt about matrices for programming contests starting in the 9th grade, and I knew enough by 11th grade to be able to understand this solution. Granted, I do think you need to know about the method beforehand in order to be able to apply it, but contests do require experience, there's no helping that.

Comment: I see, thank you. In that case, one more general question if you could - is there any specific resource you could recommend for getting to know when to apply a given method for a given contest problems' type to learn about methods like the one above? Just participating in contests and reading editorials?

Comment: @Straightfw - pretty much, I don't know any specific resource. Introduction to algorithms and The algorithm design manual are good books to learn algorithms and techniques, but they're not the definitive reference for contests by any means.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through and try to simplify the calculations at each step.  First, we should look for a non-recursive formula for `a_n`.  There is a closed form solution for this [Recurrence Relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) that gives us `a_n = A * r_1**n + B * r_2**n` where `r_1` and `r_2` are the solutions to the equation `r**2 = C * r + 1`, based on the recurrence relation in the problem.  Then we can solve for `A` and `B` so that `a_1 = a_2 = 1`.

Now, we can consider `s_n` which based on our formula for `a_n`, and rearranging terms, becomes:

```
s_n = A * (r_1 + r_1**2 + ... + r_1**n) + B * (r_2 + r_2**2 + ... + r_2**n)
```

Now, using the formula for the [Sum of a Geometric Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series), we get the formula

```
s_n = A * r_1 * (1 - r_1**n) / (1 - r_1) + B * r_2 * (1 - r_2**n) / (1 - r_2)
```

This gives you a basic outline for how to proceed.  There are a number of things to consider when actually implementing:

1. The formula for `a_n` changes if `r_1 = r_2`.  That won't happen in this problem.  Why?
2. If `r_1 = 1` or `r_2 = 1`, the formula calls for dividing by 0.
3. Integer overflow.
4. The modular arithmetic at the end.

Comment: 4 makes this a deal breaker. You have to compute the result modulo `M`, and you can only do that when division is involved if the denominator and `M` are coprime, which you are not guaranteed.

Comment: @IVlad Not necessarily.  It is possible that `s_n` can be computed directly, and then the modular arithmetic performed.

Comment: `s_n` can be huge for the given limits (of the order of `(10^18)^(10^18)`). Such a solution would never fit in the time limits of a contest, you can't even afford the memory to store such numbers.